# when running protractor with phantomjs browser, only able to run tests once

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

test code:

describe('mysite', function(){

```
var init_url = 'http://localhost/mySite/#/home';
beforeEach(function(){
    // driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    // withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()).build();
})


it('should click on toolbox and do stuff', function(){
    browser.get(init_url);
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
        console.log('current_url', url);
        expect(init_url).toEqual(init_url);
    })
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    browser.sleep(2000);
})
```

result 1st time run,

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:9515
data Zoom Pad
class active

mysite
    should click on toolbox and do stuff

Finished in 3.94 seconds
1 test, 4 assertions, 0 failures
```

2nd time run, without any interruption, just up arrow and enter:

```
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Error while running testForAngular: Error Message => 'Detected a pag
e unload event; asynchronous script execution does not work across page loads.'
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Co
nnection":"keep-alive","Content-Length":"689","Content-Type":"application/json;c
harset=UTF-8","Host":"localhost:9515"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post
":"{\"script\":\"return (function () {\\n  var attempts = arguments[0];\\n  var
callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\\n  var check = function(n) {\\n
try {\\n      if (window.angular && window.angular.resumeBootstrap) {\\n
callback([true, null]);\\n      } else if (n < 1) {\\n        if (window.angular
) {\\n          callback([false, 'angular never provided resumeBootstrap']);\\n
       } else {\\n          callback([false, 'retries looking for angular exceed
```

third time

```
  1) mysite should click on toolbox and do stuff
   Message:
     Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
   Stacktrace:
     Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (K:\Users\Congwen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:127:16)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
```

and on third time the phantomjs webserver is down, and needs to be reconnected, and afterwards it goes back to result 1:

any clues?

config file used:

```
 exports.config = {
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:9515',
     specs: [
         './ptor-tests/mysite-test.js'
     ],
     capabilities: {
         browserName: 'phantomjs',
         version: '',
         platform: 'ANY'
     },
     //baseUrl: 'http://testapp.example.com/index.html',
     rootElement: 'body',
     allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
     onPrepare: function () {},
     jasmineNodeOpts: {
         onComplete: function () {},
         isVerbose: true,
         showColors: true,
         includeStackTrace: true,
         defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
     }
 };
```

also I noticed that sometimes there's no step 2 needed and it will go directly to ECONNECT error, and sometimes it gets stuck in step 2 for a number of tests and eventually will terminate phantomjs server.

Comment: Could you provides the versions of protractor, webdriver and phantomjs ?

Comment: protractor v0.16.1, phantomjs -v1.9.2, webdriver I'm using the one that came with protractor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue with Protractor that was resolved in version 0.17 and made better in 0.18.

It's a bug with a long tail, but the TL;DR is that Protractor's .get(url) function actually uses client-side JavaScript to make the location change; this is to ensure it properly bootstraps. An unfortunate side effect of that design is that for some reason, PhantomJS takes a few seconds to navigate over properly.

The bug was resolved by adding a longer timeout to the .get function.

Github Issue: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/85

Relevant changelog entries:

## v0.18

> (10aec0f) fix(pageload): increase wait timeout
>
> The 300 ms wait caused problems when testing IE on Sauce Labs. It seems way too short. "browser.get()" invariably timed out. Increasing it solved our problem.

## v0.17

> (a0bd84b) fix(pageload): add a wait during protractor.get() to solve unload issues
>
> Some systems would not wait for the browser unload event to finish before beginning the asynchronous script execution.
>
> Closes #406. Closes #85.

I've run your test locally (with a different page, but otherwise the same code):

[image: Test]

Happy testing!

Comment: best news since I had trouble with this tool since sept 2013, ur a blessing.